# How could I found net.exe activity log in windows server 2019?

Tags: logging, database, windows-server-2019, windows-event-log, windows-net-command

I have Windows Server 2019. it is a database server(MSSQL Server) in the intranet environment.
I monitor Its Process and I found sometimes the below process runs automatically without any cause.

"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c "net localgroup administrators"
"net localgroup administrators"

I check my user's list and group list and I don't see any new users.
I don't know why net.exe runs with this command to create new local admin accounts.
how could I check its root cause and is there any solutions to find the net.exe activity log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [event id 4688](https://system32.eventsentry.com/security/event/4688) which is logged by Windows whenever a process is started. The link also explains how to configure auditing on your system to make sure this event is actually logged.

This is definitely a little suspicious, but start with looking at the event which shows you things like parent PID so you can see which process actually started this process.